# Serial communication with scientific instrument

Tags: serial-port, serial-communication

I have a scientific instrument which is controlled by an old computer running SCO Unix. I would like to write a Windows application to control the instrument to get rid of the old Unix machine.

I have been able to monitor the serial communication between the Unix PC and the instrument and have determined the setup of the serial port (baud rate, data bits, stop bits, etc.). The initial communication between the PC and the instruments is the PC sending a string of 18 null (00) characters and the instrument responding with another string of null characters.

I then connected my Windows PC directly to the instrument and sent a string of 18 null characters to the instrument (using Eltima Software Serial Port Monitor) but there was no response from the instrument. I have tried all variations of flow control and parity settings yet still can't get a response from the instrument.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Please, research the states of the DTR or RTS hardware flow control signals, because the device may control it.

Comment: Also, the software may require the characters to have a specific inter-character delay time.

Comment: When I turn on hardware flow control DTR and RTS are shown as inactive when on turn on the instrument. With XOn/XOff flow control DTR and RTS are "on".

Comment: Try to set RTS to "on" when you send data and to "off" when you wait for an answer.

Comment: Jeff was correct. I discovered some inter-character delays. The string of 18 null characters is in fact two strings of 9 null characters separated by a 40ms delay. I configured my software to send the strings to the instrument in this format but I still don't get a reply from the instrument.